# Note: Enabling the database statistics here might cause heavy traffic between the web server and the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql

> Note: Enabling the database statistics here might cause heavy traffic
>   between the web server and the MySQL server.

I got this error when I tried to add a new database in BlueHost phpMyAdmin. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: To me it looks like it's not an error, it's a warning / notification about what you expect if you enable the feature.

Answer (score -1):

First go on your Cpanel 
dont open PhpMyadmin

Click on 
MySQL® Databases
There Create New Database then Open Phpmyadmin
where your database present 
THANKS